# How do I identify which container owns which overlay directory?

Tags: docker

My `/var/lib/docker/overlay` directory contains data for my containers but the directory names are all hashed. How can I determine which container owns which overlay?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use `jq` like so:

```
 docker inspect $(docker ps -qa) |  jq -r 'map([.Name, .GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir]) | .[] | "\(.[0])\t\(.[1])"'
```

Which gives:

```
/traefik_traefik_1      /var/lib/docker/overlay/58df937e805ec0496bd09686394db421c129e975f67180e737d5af51751af49c/merged
/gitlab-runner  /var/lib/docker/overlay/4e5b06f4ee09c60e2dad3a0ce87352cead086eb8229775f6839a477b46dce565/merged
/rancher-agent  /var/lib/docker/overlay/6026bb65dd9a83c2088a05cff005a1dd824494222445bab46b7329dc331465aa/merged
```

---

Explanation:

```
docker inspect $(docker ps -qa)
```

Display full docker details.

```
jq -r
```

Parse json and output regular strings:

```
map([.Name, .GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir])
```

For each element in the original array, find the `Name` and the overlay `MergedDir`.

```
"\(.[0])\t\(.[1])"
```

Output the first two elements of the array.

Comment: You can also use it with `docker inspect $(docker image ls -aq)` to search for image layers

Answer (score 41):

Thanks to [@Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5209935/matthew) for his solution. It made me think of a Docker-only solution (without jq):

```
docker inspect -f $'{{.Name}}\t{{.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir}}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

You can also ask for a specific container using

```
docker inspect -f $'{{.Name}}\t{{.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir}}' <container_name>
```

## Explanations

I use the `-f` option of Docker inspect that allows me to use a Go template to format the output of `docker inspect`.

I use `$''` in Bash to allow special chars like `\t` in my format.

Comment: For image overlays: `docker inspect -f "{{.RepoTags}} {{.GraphDriver}}" $(docker images -q)`

Answer (score 7):

```
docker ps -qa | xargs -I{} bash -c "docker inspect {} | grep <hash> && echo {}"
```

which would give you, for example,

```
    "LowerDir": "...<hash>...",
    "MergedDir": "...<hash>...",
    "UpperDir": "...<hash>...",
    "WorkDir": "...<hash>..."
24f8ab7ae838
```

Now you can tell the container `24f8ab7ae838` owns the overlay `<hash>`.